# After leaving a chat-room I am still being shown as present in it

Tags: support, bug, chat

Sometimes, it so happens that even after I have duly left a chat-room, by clicking on the "leave" button, I am still being shown as present in the room.

It does not happen all the time but only on some occasions.

Why does this happen? Is it a bug?

Comment: How do you leave chatroom ? And yeah sometimes it's because of browser cache issue.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I leave by clicking on the"leave" button. Are there more ways of doing the same? I know that if I simply close the window then I will be shown as present in the room for some more time after that.

Comment: Yes, it happens some time. I use [leave all](https://chat.stackexchange.com/chats/leave/all) button in some cases.

Comment: @Rickross That's fine then. Then cache issue only like I said in previous comment.

Comment: Related meta post [Not able to leave a chat room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195599)

Comment: Do clear browser cookies and history after end of the session also leave the chat room and then close the chat window  first before logging  off from main  site   and then clearing  your cache . This will help i think .

Comment: Ok, thanks, yes I do follow the steps u hv mentioned except clearing browser cache .. anyways it is not an issue, I was just curious to know why it happens @SwiftPushkar